# Get yaw to point at X and Y values (2D)

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have $X$ and $Y$ coordinates. I also have another object. I need to figure out how set the yaw of the second object to point at the $X$ and $Y$ coordinates. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If the first object is at $(X,Y)$ and the second is at $(a,b)$, the vector from the second to the first is $(X-a,Y-b)$  To get the angle of that vector from the $+x$ axis (is that what you want?) you can use [atan2(Y-b,X-a)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).  It worries about the quadrants, unlike $\arctan$

Comment: Great answer, however they end up looking like [this](http://i.imgur.com/oxDtlOZ.png). The second object (at (a,b)) is the orange one, the first (the one at (X, Y) is the blue.) The little thing sticking out is the front.

Comment: It looks like you need to check the X and Y coordinate directions-math standard is $+x$ is right, $+y$ is up.  Computer graphics is otherwise.  Also check the order reversal in atan2.  Usually atan2 is in radians.

Comment: Well, reversing the order works (atan2(X-a, Y-b)), but then the object points in the direction opposite it's supposed to

Comment: Reversing the sign of the arguments will make a $180^\circ$ rotation, so then atan2(a-X,b-Y) should work.  You should try to understand why for future use.

Comment: [here's an image](http://i.imgur.com/menyM33.png) to show what I mean, doing a-X didn't work either.

Comment: The images don't help me understand what is happening.  We might as well set $a=b=0$  Then if $X=3, Y=4$, you should get $53.13^\circ$

Comment: That's what I'm getting.

Comment: That is correct in radians.  Now in normal math orientation it is a little north of northeast.  Where does it point for you?

Comment: It's pointing North East.

Comment: Sorry, that is correct.  And $(3,4)$ is a little north of northeast from the origin, so it should be pointing correctly

Comment: It should be pointing north west based on my image, what should I do?

Comment: You need to understand why your image is showing northwest.  It probably is in the coordinate system you are using.  What are the coordinates of the two objects, which way is $+x$, which way is $+y$?

Comment: y is the distance from the top of the screen to the object, if you decrease a y value, it goes up. X is the distance between the left side of the screen and the object. If you add to X, the object goes right. (the two values are as you suggested, (X = 0, Y = 0, a = 3, b = 4)

Comment: The handedness of your coordinates is backwards from normal.  A vector $(3,4)$ then points south of southeast.  I specified what is standard quite a while ago.  atan2 is working fine, but you need to resolve the signs to match your coordinates.  You also reversed $(X,Y)$ and $(a,b)$ compared to my comment.

Comment: Reversing them so they match your comment now makes the second object point south west. I'm using `atan2(second.Y - first.Y, second.X - first.X)` (which makes `atan2(0 - 4, 0 - 3)`)

Comment: what should the atan2 calculation be?

Comment: I used $atan2(OBJECT2_{y} - OBJECT1_{y}, OBJECT2_{x} - OBJECT1_{x}) - \pi / 2$ which worked fine.

Comment: Better check all the quadrants to make sure.  I would be concerned about the axis orientations.